# Computing $\int_C(x-y)dz$ with Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Define a curve, C, as the intersection of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z-2x-2y=1$. Orient C counterclockwise as seen from the point $(0,0,10)$. Then calculate
$$\int_C(x-y)dz$$
My thoughts: We can rearrange the equations for C to get the intersection of the ellipse $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=3$ and the plane $z-2x-2y=1$
The integral itself
$$=\int_C(x-y)d(1+2x+2y)=2\int_C(x-y)dx+(x-y)dy$$

Now we have curlF$=(0,0,2)$ and I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I parametrise the ellipse?

Answer (score 0):

1. By Stokes' theorem:
   $$
   \oint_C (x-y)dz = \iint_S \nabla\times \vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\;dS = \iint_S \frac{2}{3}\; dS = \frac{2}{3} A(S),
   $$
   as
   $$
   \nabla\times\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n} = (-1,-1,0)\cdot \frac{1}{3}(-2,-2,1) = \frac{4}{3}
   $$
   Now, we must compute the area of the ellipse $S$. It equals the area inside 
   $
   (x−1)^2+(y−1)^2=3
   $, that is, $3\pi$, divided by the cosine of the angle $\gamma$ between the $z$ axis and the plane $z-2x-2y=1$:
   $$
   A(S)=\frac{3\pi}{\cos{\gamma}}=\frac{3\pi}{\frac{1}{3}}=9\pi
   $$
   We end up with
   $$
   \oint_C (x-y)dz =  \frac{4}{3} A(S) = 12 \pi
   $$
2. Alternatively, with the classical way:
   $$
   \vec{r}(t):
   \begin{cases}
   x=-1+\sqrt{3}\cos t\\
   y=-1+\sqrt{3}\sin t\\
   z=1-2x-2y=2\sqrt{3}(\cos t+\sin t)
   \end{cases}
   \quad t\in [0,2\pi]
   $$
   It follows that
   $$
   \oint_C (x-y)dz = \int_0^{2\pi}\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot \vec{r}'(t)\, dt
   = \int_0^{2\pi} 6 (\cos t - \sin t)^2\, dt = 12 \pi
   $$

Comment: Thanks. How do we know that the area of the ellipse is $3\pi$? Am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: As you wrote, the ellipse has equation $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=3$…in fact it is a specific ellipse: a circle of radius $\sqrt{3}$! It follows that the area equals $3\pi$.

Comment: Yes, but surely it's intersection with that plane is at an angle, so the resulting shape is an ellipse?

Comment: Oh wait, I see it

Comment: No you are right! I have fixed it.